Am I using KQL incorrectly, or is there another reason?
I using sdk 4.x version.
I refer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

First of all, The rest of the KQL features are functioning. For example,"keyword * (LastModifiedTime > 2023-07-14) " Or "title :   Keyword  OR  author :   Keyword" and so on.
When searching by keyword query with URL(path), this filter does not apply.
So I'm wondering if my query is incorrect, and I'm curious how to change it.
When I tested the API directly that graph explorer, it worked as expected,
but it didn't when I used the SDK.
I request Query that "keyword path:\"https://~~\"".
Expected response (tested in Graph Explorer):
"value": [
    {
        "searchTerms": [
            "test"
        ],
        "hitsContainers": [
          

Actual response (tested in my code):
"value": [
{
  "searchTerms": [
    "test",
    "https://~~\""
  ],
  "hitsContainers": [
    

Despite sending the same query, the responses differ in their "searchTerms" content.
Below is the code snippet of my request:
 var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
 requests = new[]
 {
     new
     {
         entityTypes = new[] { "driveItem" },
         query = new
         {
             queryString =  searchQuery // = test  path:\"https://(url)\"
         },
         from = 0,
         size = 15,
         region = "KOR"

     }
   }
  });

Could someone please help me understand why the filter is not applying correctly when querying with a URL, and how I might adjust my approach? Thank you!

See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/kql-quick-reference

It was just my mistake that request a keyword problem.  It's working now.
